# How to enable argon2 support in PHP?

Tags: php, xampp, argon2-ffi

I'm creating a simple sign in/log in web app and I'm using Argon2id to hash the password when i run it it gives `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "PASSWORD_ARGON2ID" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

I'm using Xampp and it has a PHP 8.2.0 version, based on my research I have to locate the PHP source code and configure PHP with Argon support but I can't find the PHP's source code there. Is it possible to enable the Argon2 support with Xampp's PHP?
[image: Xampp php directory bit it doesn't contain PHP source code]

Comment: XAMPP will deliver a precompiled PHP install. If the build doesn't include Argon support and you want it, you'd have to recompile PHP from the [publicly available source code](https://github.com/php/php-src). This isn't necessarily a trivial task. Ask yourself though, do you really _need_ it? Is there a problem for you with using bcrypt?